# Python Sqlalchemy 'Invalid SQL data type' Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type  (67) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: UPDATE table SET first=?, second=? WHERE table.id = ?]
[parameters: (('Test',), 'Test', 5)]
```

while running this code:

```
...

    test = session.query(Table).filter(Table.test == test_var).first()
    test.first = "Test",
    test.second = "Test"
    session.commit()

...
```

for Model:

```
class Table(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test = Column(String)
    first = Column(String)
    second = Column(String)
```

The first Parameter looks like a list, how could this happen and how can i fix this? This code already runs a few times without any issues, that's why i am confused about this.

Thx in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you intend to include a comma at the end of this line?

> ```
>    test.first = "Test",
> ```

I believe this is causing python to interpret `test.first` as a tuple, which it cannot insert into the table since the table is expecting a string type.

Comment: OMG... For real i looked and tested more then 60 minutes and did not realized this comma... No words about this *facepalm*